# EasyAdminBundle: Validation not working on CKEditorType

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony4, easyadmin

In my admin panel created with [EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html), my form validations only work with fields that do not have the `CKEditorType`. Some fields need to be edited so I implemented a WYSIWYG with [FOSCKEditorBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/index.html).

**Snippet from field concerned:**

```
- { property: 'content', type: 'FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType'}
```

When I submit the form with an empty 'content' field, I get an `InvalidArgumentException` with the error: `Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given.` instead of a validation error like *Please fill in this field.*

**Snippet from field concerned without CKEditor:**

```
- { property: 'content' }
```

=> validation works perfectly.

**My entity field:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    private $content;
```

The Symfony profiler shows that this field indeed has a `required` attribute.

How can enable the validations with the `CKEditor` field type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about ckeditor. All you need is to fix your content setter to accept **NULL** through the argument. Then the validation process should be fired correctly:

```
public function setContent(?string $content) {
    $this->content = $content;

    retrun $this;
}
```

Validation is performed after request values are set to form data (in your case entity) fields. You can find form submit flow here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did my validation work when I used the default `textType` field and not a `CKEditorType` field?

Comment: I think It depends on the form component, version and FosCkedito version, this kind of hack is fixed with last versions... I don't know where exactly, but it's all about data transforms. There's an issue in github talking about the trick I will try to find it. Any way Ckeditor does not ` implement `DataTransformerInterface` but TextType does. Could you give me some informations about your versions!!

Comment: I am using "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle" version 1.2.0

Comment: This did not work for me. I now get an SQL Integrity constraint violation. For me, Easy Admin is not validating the form at all, and gets as far as trying to write the data to the database.

Comment: Could give more details about the constraint violatio

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this by leaning on Symfony's Form builder, I've added constraint "NotBlank" to the "CKEditorField".

It looks like this at the controller:

```
...
use App\Admin\Field\CKEditorField;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
...

public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{    
    return [
        IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
        TextField::new('title')->setFormTypeOption('required',true),
        CKEditorField::new('description')->setFormTypeOption('required',true)
        ->setFormTypeOption('constraints',[
            new NotBlank(),
        ])
    ];
}
...
```

And the EasyAdmin field class file which is used in controller (add this to follow EasyAdmin's approach):

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Field;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

final class CKEditorField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null):self
    {
        return (new self())

            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(CKEditorType::class)
            ->onlyOnForms()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment to improve search engine indexing: This answer also works as an example of implementing the CKEditor Bundle in an Easy Admin Controller.